# golang comparing two structures with their interface arguments

Tags: go

I am currently studying golang. I have OOP knowledge especially on C++.
Here is the example code:
package main

```
import "fmt"

type Person interface{
    // Some other functions
}

type info struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

type example struct {
    Description string
    Other int
}

func (p info) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v (%v years)", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func (p example) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v (%v years)", p.Description, p.Other)
}

// The argument cannot be changed
// Try not to access into Person because there will be other different structures
// that implement the Person interface
func compare(p1, p2 Person) bool {
    return p1 == p2
}

func main() {
    a := info{"Arthur Dent", 42}
    z := info{"Zaphod Beeblebrox", 9001}
    b := example{"Arthur Dent", 42}
    fmt.Println(a, z)
    fmt.Println(compare(a, b))
}
```

As you can see, there is a interface call Person, implemented by a structure call info. There are functions in Person but for simplifying the question, I didn't post those. The problem now is I have implemented the method String for info but the compare function takes Person elements as input.

Suppose the declaration of  the compare function cannot be changed and use only Person in the body of this functions, how can I solve the problem or achieve the compara functionality?

Comment: Use `==` to compare values for equality: `func compare(p1, p2 Person) bool { return p1 == p2 }`.  This seems obvious.  Perhaps the question is asking you to add methods to Person?

Comment: You are absolutely right, could you input it as an answer below and with a little bit explaination why could it work just with p1 instead of a function call?

Comment: I updated a bit of the code, now it doesn't work. Suppose there is another structure but with the same elements (could be in different order), how can I compare those two object now? I am implementing a stack with array and linkedlist in golang and trying to compare them even they are in different implementation. It always return false if they are from different structure.

Comment: You are asking a different question in the edit. I answered the original question.

Comment: Sorry, I will post a new question instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specification says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.

and

> Struct values are comparable if all their fields are comparable. Two struct values are equal if their corresponding non-blank fields are equal.

All of the struct fields are comparable.

Given this, you can use the equal operator:

```
func compare(p1, p2 Person) bool { 
    return p1 == p2
}
```